# Shisei's double irises

Tags: from-the-new-world

The character [Shisei Kaburagi](http://shinsekaiyori.wikia.com/wiki/Shisei_Kaburagi) in Shinsekai Yori has double irises. At the same time, he is (one of) the most powerful telekinesis users.

After watching the anime, I haven't found any reason why he has double irises, nor why they help him (if they do).

Is this explained in the manga?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably not explained in the manga, because [the manga is... well, not great](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/6373/1908).

Kaburagi Shisei's eyes are mentioned in the novel, though. On page 666 of the one-volume edition (book V, chapter 3; right before Hino Koufuu is slain), we have:

> 切れ長の非常に大きな目は、澄みきっていた。顔の造作も整っており、ハンサムと言ってもいいくらいだ。その異様な眼球を別にすればだが。
>
> 鏑木康星氏には、片目に二つずつ、合わせて四つの虹彩があり、薄闇の中で、ぎらぎらと琥珀色に輝いていた。これは鏑木家に代々伝わる特異な遺伝的特徴で、一般人とは隔絶した呪力の証なのだという。

Roughly translated,

> His unusually-large, almond-shaped eyes were limpid. His face was so well-sculpted, I might even have called him handsome - save for his bizarre eyes.
>
> Kaburagi Shisei had four irises - two in each eye. They shone through the darkness, glowing the color of amber. That peculiarity was genetic in origin, and had been passed down the Kaburagi lineage for generations. They were a testament to the fact that his cantus was on an entirely different level than that of the common people.

So I guess it's just some sort of genetic weirdness in his family, probably a benign phenotypic side effect to whatever mutation makes people of his family particularly powerful PK users.